# Find out how many distinct triplets of numbers, from give N integers , have their sum divisible by integer M

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

Given N integers. A triplet of numbers is a set of three numbers whose sum is divisible by a constant M. Find out how many distinct triplets of numbers, from given N integers , have their sum divisible by M.
What would be an optimal algorithm to find the answer to this problem ?

Please Note: Every element is treated as different irrespective of their actual value .

[This is the link to the actual problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/mathison-and-the-divisible-trio-a0a169b0/description/)

Comment: It is worth to show own thoughts.

Comment: Right! I have added a case that I am confused about for which I believe even the actual source of problem is not giving correct answer . And I am also removing the constraints since I do not know an optimal solution myself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an O(N + M^2) solution.

First create an array C[M] where C[i] contains the number of the input numbers that are i mod M. This takes O(N) time.

Then for each i <= j <= k with i+j+k=0 mod M, count triples (a, b, c) with a=i (mod M), b=j (mod M), c=k(mod M).

We can do this efficiently by looping over i and j, and finding the unique k that causes the sum to be 0 (mod M), ignoring the combination if k<j. We have to be careful counting to make sure that we count unique triples; if i, j, k are distinct the number of triples is simply C[i] * C[j] * C[k], but if two or more of the indices are the same, we have to be careful not to allow the same number to be reused. For example, if i=j!=k, then there's choose(C[i], 2) * C[k] triples.

Here's complete code, which produces the correct answer 26 for the given test case:

```
def choose2(n):
    return n * (n-1) // 2

def choose3(n):
    return n * (n-1) * (n-2) // 6

def triples(A, M):
    C = [0] * M
    for a in A:
        C[a % M] += 1
    T = 0
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(i, M):
            k = (-i - j) % M
            if k < j:
                continue
            if i == j == k:
                T += choose3(C[i])
            elif i == j:
                T += choose2(C[i]) * C[k]
            elif j == k:
                T += C[i] * choose2(C[j])
            else:
                T += C[i] * C[j] * C[k]
    return T

print(triples([1, 10, 4, 3, 2, 5, 0, 1, 9, 5], 5))
```

Comment: print(triples([1,1,1,4], 3))  gives output 4 but clearly only two triplets are possible (1,1,1) and (1,1,4) . Thus correct answer should be 2 I guess .  Also thank you for helping me out :))

Comment: @Pratap Singh Link example shows that  1's in `1 10 4 3 2 5 0 1 9 5` are distinct - output counts both (0, 1, 2); and (1, 2, 7); index sets. The same for two 5's (indices 5 and 9). In this case there are three ways to choose two ones from [1,1,1,4]

Comment: @MBo You are right . Oh god! My brain is finally at peace .Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would first compute [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) for each number after dividing it by M. Then I would sort all N numbers by their remainders.

This is N*log(N) cost.

Then for each pair of numbers I would search if there is matching remainder among all numbers which will give me sum divisible by M.

There is N^2 pairs and each lookup is a binary search - log(N).

So I see solution having cost N^2*log(N), but maybe there is something more sophisticated and cheaper one.

Comment: I think this solution is right, but you need to to more than see if there's a matching remainder, you have to count how many remainders there are (you can do this by finding the top and bottom of the range of things with the right remainder with two binary searches to avoid increasing the complexity), and subtracting 0, 1 or 2 depending whether none, one or both of the pair are in that range. I think a problem is that N can be up to 10^5, so N^2 is probably too large for the program to be fast enough.